# Casting error from Option[Double] to Double in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections

I am facing a problem in casting from Option[Double] to Double. I am getting the following exception error:

```
scala.Some cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

val ty = ttnew.distinct().leftOuterJoin(rank).map{ case ((key),(c,d)) => (key,c._1,c._2,c._3,d.getOrElse(Double).asInstanceOf[Double]) }
```

Please Help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
d.getOrElse(Double).asInstanceOf[Double]
```

makes no sense.

Assuming `d` is an `Option[Double]` if you want to have a `Double` you cannot cast it, you need to get the value "out of" the `Option`.

`getOrElse` allows you to get the value if present, and provide a fallback value if absent (i.e. `None`).

For example:

```
d.getOrElse(0) // 0, or anything that makes sense as a fallback
```

If `d` has type `Option[Double]` then `d.getOrElse(0)` has type `Double`.

Comment: So, I am suppose to change it from d.getOrElse(Double).asInstanceOf[Double] to d.getOrElse(0)

Comment: yes, where `0` can be replaced to any reasonable default in your domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try and get back to you If error persist.

Comment: Does this solution works. Because when I am trying .getOrElse(0) it gives me type mismatch error . It says found : Int and required is Option[Double]

Answer (score 5):

that's not how you deal with `Option`. Use `.getOrElse` or a `.map`

```
val ty=ttnew.distinct().leftOuterJoin(rank).map{ case ((key),(c,d)) => (key,c._1,c._2,c._3,d.getOrElse(Double).asInstanceOf[Double]) }
```

probably (in this situation) you will want to do `d.getOrElse(<a-good-default-value-like-zero-maybe>)`

other situations maybe you want to propagate the meaning of `Option` (the value may not exist), and in those cases you should use the `.map`:

```
val res: Option[String] = optionalDouble.map(doubleValue => callSomeFunctionThatConvertsDoubleToString(value))
```

you can even do other things using pattern matching and extractors. for instance, using `.collect` (it's a `.map`, but there may be cases not covered):

```
val ty=ttnew.distinct().leftOuterJoin(rank).collect{ case ((key),(c,Some(d))) => (key,c._1,c._2,c._3,d) }
```

Comment: But, how map can be used in this case. It may be silly question to ask but, I am totally new to scala

Comment: added some alternatives @rrr

Comment: By using this collect case, It will cover all cases from d ?

Comment: And, also I want to know by using collect case, it will not give classcastException error for Null values?